# How do I get identity from one sproc and pass it in to another sproc?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi all i'm looking for a way to pass in a generated id from a sproc to another sproc.

i.e.

```
@name varchar(12),
@descript varchar(55)
@test_date date,
@test_result varchar(1)
BEGIN
   EXEC ts_create_item @name, @descript
END
if (@test_date is not null) or (isnull(@test_result_id,'')!='')
BEGIN
   Exec ts_update_test_results @itemid(generated from the sproc before), @test_date, @test_result
End
```

Is there a way to do this in sql server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an output variable

so you would declare the previous proc like

```
Create proc SomeProc (@parm1 int, @parm2 int, @id int = null OUTPUT)
as
Begin
  ...do some insert
  select @id = scope_identity()
End
```

And remember, OUTPUT has to be specified both when declaring and assigning the parameter 
ie.

```
Exec someproc @parm1, @parm2, @id OUTPUT
```

Alternately you can use a local variable to hold the result

e.g.

```
create proc somesample(@in int)
as
Begin
    select @in * 2
End 

declare @var int
exec @var = somesample 1
print @var
2
```

Comment: np, let me know if you have any problems.